# How to get the name of a folder on a website

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm looking for a way for me to get the folder name which is located on (for example) `http://example.com/download/"foldername here"`

The reason for this is because I have a c# program which always downloads a .zip if you don't allready have it, but currently it won't download a new version.

Example: Currently it downloads from `http://example.com/download/1.0/file.zip`, if you allready have the folder it checks for, it won't download it, but if you do have that folder, it won't download from `http://example.com/download/2.0/file.zip`, which contains the new version. I have made a file which contains the current version, but how can I get my program to check that file against the folder in which the newest version resides?

Edit: I reworked my code so it downloads a `version.txt` file first and reads it contents, which contains the latest version of the download.

Code:

```
if (radUseFile.Checked)
{
//get latest version on website
WebClient modver = new WebClient();
modver.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
modver.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/download/version.txt", tempdir _
+ "version.txt");
using (StreamReader ver = new StreamReader(tempdir + "version.txt"))
{
    siteversion = ver.ReadToEnd();
}
File.Delete(tempdir + "version.txt");
if (Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    if (File.Exists(folder + "\\version.txt"))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(folder + "\\version.txt"))
        {
            latestversion = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        if (latestversion != siteversion)
        {
            uptodate = false;
        }
        else
        {
            uptodate = true;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    uptodate = false;
}
if (!uptodate)
{
    //download and extract the files
    WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
    label4.Text = "Downloading full client. May take a while";
    this.Update();
    downloader.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    downloader.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/download" + siteversion _
+ "/zipfile.zip", templocation + "zipfile.zip");

    label4.Text = "Extracting...";
    Shell32.Shell sc = new Shell32.Shell();
    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempdir);
    Shell32.Folder output = sc.NameSpace(tempdir);
    Shell32.Folder input = sc.NameSpace(tempdir + "zipfile.zip");
    output.CopyHere(input.Items(), 4);

    label4.Text = "Cleaning up...";
    File.Delete(tempdir + "zipfile.zip");

    new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer().FileSystem.CopyDirectory(tempdir,_
folderlocation, true);

    Directory.Delete(tempdir, true);

    uptodate = true;
}
}
else
{
uptodate = true;
}
```

This works for now, but I'm pretty sure this code can be improved, or the entire method as to how it takes the latest version

Comment: Url paths doesn't have to map to a phsical path. For ex `http://foo.bar/download/mostrecent/` can map to `3.0` today, but `4.0` tomorrow.

Comment: Do you want to get the list of all 'folders' in `http://foo.bar/download/` ?

Comment: @I4V I was hoping for something like that, although how can I get that to work exactly? By making an extra folder which redirects to the latest version?

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly, I guess that would be a future possibility so people will be able to select what version they want, but for now I just want it to find the latest version

Comment: In this case Andrew's answer is the only option. You can not find the folder name if you don't have it written somewhere. It can be a text file or html page.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly So the way I have my code now (in my question, I've updated it using Andrew's answer), is my only option for getting the latest version's folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a text file, containing the latest version number and where to download it from, in a permanent location, say `http://example.com/download/latestversion.txt`. Then use `WebClient.DownloadString` to retrieve that file, and take the appropriate action depending on the content of the file.

Comment: That is an option, but isn't that taking the long way around? I'm pretty sure there's an easier way which doesn't require an extra temp download.